# Tonelli's Lemma - Stein and Shakarchi Doubt

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Stein and Shakarchi state a theorem by Tonelli in "Real Analysis" Ch 2, Section 3.2 as:

"Suppose $f(x,y)$ is non-negative, measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{d^1} \times \mathbb{R}^{d^2}$ (where $x$ lives in the former and $y$ in the latter). Then, for almost every $y \in \mathbb{R}^{d^2}$

(a) The slice $f^y$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{d^1}$

(b) the function defined by  $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d^1}} f^y(x)dx$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R^{d^2}}$.

(c) $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d^2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d^1}} f^y(x)dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f dx dy$ "

Now, I am able to understand what (a) means - simply, holding $y$ as a constant, the slice $f^y(x)$ is measurable for a.e. y. However, I do not understand what it means for the function $F(y) = $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d^1}} f^y(x)dx $ from (b) to be measurable for a.e. $y \in \mathbb{R^{d^2}}$. I did suppose it could mean that, there could exist some $y_i$ in some null-set $A \in \mathbb{R^{d^2}}$and  $\exists a > 0 $ s.t. $\{y \in \mathbb{R^{d^2}}: F(y_i) < a\}$ is not measurable. Isn't measurability a global property?

How do I make sense of (b) given the almost-everywhere property?

Comment: My guess is that the "almost every" should have only been applied to statement (a). Note that "almost every" doesn't make sense in the context of (c) either.

Comment: I agree. Would you say the reason is similar to what I said about measurability being a "global" property? Also, would you have a citation with a more appropriate (and similar) statement of this lemma?

Comment: If we consider Borel measurability, then the slice in (a) will be Borel measurable everywhere, not just almost everywhere.